# Python conditions statement logic

Tags: python, selenium, conditional-statements

Im beginner on selenium & python and i trying to understand the logic of condition statement but it doesn't take the second condition into account :

What i try to do :

[image]

PS : I put " ? " because I'm not sure if is that

My code :

```
users = []

elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//body//div[@class='PZuss']//a[@class='FPmhX notranslate  _0imsa ']")
url = "https://www.instagram.com/"

    # Generate a list where to put the followers name
for i in range(100):
        val = elems[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')
        users.append(url+val)
    
print(users)
 for follower in users:
        #Iterate into the list
        browser.get(follower)
        sleep(2)
        
        followButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
        
        print(follower_count)
        print(following_count)     
        
        if int(follower_count) == 0:
            follower_count = int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/span/span').text.replace(",",""))
            following_count = int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/span/span').text.replace(",",""))
                
               continue  #don't know if i need this word ?  
                    
                if browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'YW5vbnltb3VzX3Byb2ZpbGVfcGlj')]"):
                        print("profil haven't profil pic")
        
                             continue
        
        else:
            print("eligible")
            followButton.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of what you're trying to achieve is this.

```
if int(follower_count) == 0:
        follower_count = int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/span/span').text.replace(",",""))
        following_count = int(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/span/span').text.replace(",",""))
                
        if browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'YW5vbnltb3VzX3Byb2ZpbGVfcGlj')]"):
            print("profil haven't profil pic")

        else:
            print("eligible")
            followButton.click()
```

You do not need the `continue` for the code to work

The second if statement is within the first if statement, with the `else` a part of the second if statement. The indented block of code is within the first if statement and is only run if follower_count is equal to 0, otherwise it will skip the if statement and go to the next value in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use logical operators here. Assume you have your conditions check and validation logic in three dedicated methods:

```py
def check_condition_one(*args):
    pass  # You evaluate your conditions here


def check_condition_two(*args):
    pass  # You evaluate your conditions here


def validate(*args):
    pass  # you implement your validation logic here
```

Then you do like this:

```
for user in users:
    if check_condition_one(user) and check_condition_two(user):
        validate(user)
```

So you validate a user when both the conditions have evaluated to `True`. Otherwise nothing happens.

**P.S.** - `continue` just skips the rest of the code till the end of current loop iteration and proceeds to the next one if any.

Comment: Nice great idea @alexey-r !!, i will test that, thank you